# How to fully resolve errors in packaging a Kivy app for Android that arise from the file configure.ac of the libffi package?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, buildozer

Can anyone help me with some insights into resolving the following error in using the

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

command:

```
[INFO]:    Building libffi for arm64-v8a
[DEBUG]:   Create directory /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs
[DEBUG]:   Create directory /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/kdvpainlevecompatibilityapp
[DEBUG]:   Create directory /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/libs_collections/kdvpainlevecompatibilityapp/arm64-v8a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi
[DEBUG]:   -> running autogen.sh
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:8: warning: The macro `AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:8: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2081: AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:8: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:74: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:74: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:3: AC_FUNC_MMAP_BLACKLIST is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:74: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:91: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:91: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:91: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:118: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:118: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    m4/asmcfi.m4:1: GCC_AS_CFI_PSEUDO_OP is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:118: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:122: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:122: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:122: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:138: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:138: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:138: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:185: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:185: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:185: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:215: warning: _LT_CMD_GLOBAL_SYMBOLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
[DEBUG]:    aclocal.m4:778: LT_SYS_SYMBOL_USCORE is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:215: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:310: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:310: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:310: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2997: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
[DEBUG]:    ./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:418: the top level
[DEBUG]:    configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
[DEBUG]:          If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
[DEBUG]:          See the Autoconf documentation.
[DEBUG]:    configure:8578: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LD
[DEBUG]:    autoreconf: error: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
Exception in thread background thread for pid 108286:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
configure.ac:8: warning: The macro `AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' is obsolete.
configure.ac:8: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2081: AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM is expanded from...
configure.ac:8: the top level
configure.ac:74: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:74: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:3: AC_FUNC_MMAP_BLACKLIST is expanded from...
configure.ac:74: the top level
configure.ac:91: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
configure.ac:91: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
configure.ac:91: the top level
configure.ac:118: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:118: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
m4/asmcfi.m4:1: GCC_AS_CFI_PSEUDO_OP is expanded from...
configure.ac:118: the top level
configure.ac:122: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:122: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:122: the top level
configure.ac:138: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:138: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:138: the top level
configure.ac:185: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:185: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:215: warning: _LT_CMD_GLOBAL_SYMBOLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
aclocal.m4:778: LT_SYS_SYMBOL_USCORE is expanded from...
configure.ac:215: the top level
configure.ac:310: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:310: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
configure.ac:310: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2997: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:8578: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LD
autoreconf: error: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1262, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 680, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 99, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 158, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 28, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: export WARNINGS=
autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
configure.ac:8: warning: The macro `AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM' is obsolete.
configure.ac:8: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2081: AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM is expanded from...
configure.ac:8: the top level
configure.ac:74: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:74: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:3: AC_FUNC_MMAP_BLACKLIST is expanded from...
configure.ac:74: the top level
configure.ac:91: warning: The macro `AC_HEADER_STDC' is obsolete.
configure.ac:91: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/headers.m4:704: AC_HEADER_STDC is expanded from...
configure.ac:91: the top level
configure.ac:118: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:118: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
m4/asmcfi.m4:1: GCC_AS_CFI_PSEUDO_OP is expanded from...
configure.ac:118: the top level
configure.ac:122: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:122: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:122: the top level
configure.ac:138: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:138: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:138: the top level
configure.ac:185: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_COMPILE' is obsolete.
configure.ac:185: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2847: AC_TRY_COMPILE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:692: _AS_IF_ELSE is expanded from...
lib/m4sugar/m4sh.m4:699: AS_IF is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2249: AC_CACHE_VAL is expanded from...
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2270: AC_CACHE_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:215: warning: _LT_CMD_GLOBAL_SYMBOLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
aclocal.m4:778: LT_SYS_SYMBOL_USCORE is expanded from...
configure.ac:215: the top level
configure.ac:310: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:310: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
configure.ac:310: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_HELP_STRING' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:204: AC_HELP_STRING is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: AC_PROG_LD is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_RUN' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2997: AC_TRY_RUN is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:251: LIBFFI_CHECK_LINKER_FEATURES is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:418: warning: The macro `AC_TRY_LINK' is obsolete.
configure.ac:418: You should run autoupdate.
./lib/autoconf/general.m4:2920: AC_TRY_LINK is expanded from...
acinclude.m4:353: LIBFFI_ENABLE_SYMVERS is expanded from...
configure.ac:418: the top level
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:8578: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LD
autoreconf: error: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1


And I am running this on google colab after having installed most of the required packages using relevant shell commands.
```

I did include autogen.sh and configure.ac files in the folders that form the .buildozer repository but in vain. I am trying to use this to package an Kivy app to be able to run on Android which is also based on differential-algebraic algorithms from Sympy.

Comment: Try installing the packages that are listed as `autoreconf: configure.ac: not using`. Like `Gettext`, `Libtool`, `Intltool`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation. The next error I get is this and I think I have installed both sympy mpmath with the most recent version -->

  STDOUT:
/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/sympy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/sympy/setup.py:49: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
  from distutils.core import setup, Command
Please install the mpmath package with a version >= 0.19

Comment: I believe that is a warning, not an error.

Comment: STDERR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1262, in <module>
    main()
  ......File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_255:

Comment: These are some fragments of the lines that precede the deprecationwarning actually.